# Multiple inheritance with Abstract class and Interface

Tags: c#

I have written the following code in C#.NET

```
public interface IWork
{
    void func();

}
public abstract  class WorkClass
{
    public void func()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling Abstract Class Function");
    }

}

public class MyClass:WorkClass,IWork
{

}
```

On compiling, I didn't get any error. Compiler is not forcing me to  implement the method "func();" in "MyClass", which has been derived from the interface "IWork".Latter, I can gracefully create a instance of the class "MyClass" and call the function "func()". Why the compiler is not forcing me to implement the "func()" method in the "MyClass"(which has been derived from "IWork" interface? Is it a flaw in C#?

Comment: Because the class `MyClass` inherits this functions from the abstract class `WorkClass`- therefore it is implemented.

Comment: If you want to be forced, lose it in your base `class` or lose it in your `interface` and mark it `abstract` in your base `class`.

Comment: Just a side note: There's no such thing as "multiple inheritance" in C#. You can only inherit from 1 class but implement many interfaces.

Comment: This is actually not even a bad question. I had a long time until I fully understood the idea behind interfaces...interfaces are actually only needed if there is no multiple inheritance. Otherwise you just create abstract classes as (implemented) interfaces and inherite those. This is the programmer's paradise. ;)

Comment: An interface is merely a contract, or a promise if you will. I give you an object of `IDog` and with that I promise it will be able to `Poo()`. Whether `class Dog:Animal,IAnimal` implements it or not is not an issue when `class Animal` implements it. The promise is met.

Answer (score 15):

While reading about this subject, I found I couldn't easily put it all together in my head, so I wrote the following piece of code, which acts as a cheat-sheet for how C# works.  Hope it helps someone.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void FunctionA();
    void FunctionB();
    void FunctionC();
}

public abstract class MyAbstractClass : IMyInterface
{
    public void FunctionA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "FunctionA() implemented in abstract class. Cannot be overridden in concrete class." );
    }

    public virtual void FunctionB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "FunctionB() implemented in abstract class. Can be overridden in concrete class." );
    }

    public abstract void FunctionC();
}

public class MyConcreteClass : MyAbstractClass, IMyInterface
{
    public override void FunctionB()
    {
        base.FunctionB();
        Console.WriteLine( "FunctionB() implemented in abstract class but optionally overridden in concrete class." );
    }

    public override void FunctionC()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "FunctionC() must be implemented in concrete class because abstract class provides no implementation." );
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        IMyInterface foo = new MyConcreteClass();
        foo.FunctionA();
        foo.FunctionB();
        foo.FunctionC();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Gives the following output:

FunctionA() implemented in abstract class.  Cannot be overridden in concrete class.

FunctionB() implemented in abstract class. Can be overridden in concrete class.

FunctionB() implemented in abstract class but optionally overridden in concrete class.

FunctionC() must be implemented in concrete class because abstract class provides no implementation.

Answer (score 5):

To better understand the concept behind interfaces, I just give you the correct code of your implementation:

```
public interface IWork{
    void func();
}

public abstract class WorkClass,IWork{
    public void func(){
        Console.WriteLine("Calling Abstract Class Function");
    }
}

public class MyClass:WorkClass{
...
}
```

The basic rule: You need to include the interface always where the implementation is. So if you create a method within an abstract classes and define an interface of this method, you'll need to implement the interface into your abstract class and then all subclasses will automatically implement this interface.

As a matter of fact, interfaces have 2 kind of functions you can use them for:

1) As a "real" interface providing a generic handling of any class implementing the interface, so you can handle several kind of classes just by one interface (without knowing their real class names). While "handling" means: Calling a method.

2) As a help for other (framework) programmers not to mess up with your code. If you want to be sure that an method won't be replaced with another name, you define an interface for your class containing all "must have" method names. Even if the method is called nowhere, your programmer will get an compile error message when he changed the method name.

Now you can easily handle your `Myclass` just by the interface `IWork`.

Answer (score 3):

Because the `abstract` class implements the interface.

If your class `MyClass` would not inherit from `WorkClass` you would get an error saying `'MyClass' does not implement interface member 'IWork.func()'`.

But you also inherit from `WorkClass`, which actually implements the methods that the interface requires.

You can mark `func()` as abstract if you want to force the classes that inherits from it to implement it like this:

```
public abstract class WorkClass
{
    public abstract void func();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the classes above in my solution.
It inherits the abstract class so the derived class have the func() method definition. This is the reason it was not able to show compiled errors.

Answer (score 0):

`func()` is not marked as `abstract` in the `WorkClass` so you don't need to implement it in any classes that derive from `WorkClass`.

`WorkClass` implements the `IWork` interface so you don't need to implement it in `MyClass` because it inherits `func()` from `WorkClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the func method in the abstract class is a non-virtual method, so the compiler thinks this method is a implementation of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

When you extend `MyClass` to `WorkClass`, the method `func()` (which has been defined), is inherited.

So, when the interface `IWork` is implemented, the method 'func()' has already been defined. So, there are no more undefined methods in `MyClass`.

So, the class `MyClass` is a concrete class, due to which you are able to create a `MyClass` object without any compilation errors.